# How to detect shift key pressed on range input?

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events

I'm trying to synchronize two sliders when the shift key is pressed.
However, the problem is that e.shiftKey is undefined for the range input event.

I tried using the onmousedown event, which does report e.shiftKey, but it doesn't set the range value correctly.

How can I detect if the shift key is being pressed on range input?

```js
$('input[type=range]').on("input",function(e){
 $('#value').text(this.value);
  if(e.shiftKey){
   var newValue = this.value;
   $('input[type=range]').each(function(){this.value=newValue});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<input type="range">
<input type="range">
<span id="value"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

(jQuery is optional, just using it for convenience)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for the shiftKey regardless the click on the range input:

```js
var sync = false;
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey) {
        sync = true;
    }
});
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.shiftKey == false) {
        sync = false;
    }
});
$('input[type=range]').on("input",function(e){
    $('#value').text(this.value);
    if (sync) {
        var newValue = this.value;
        $('input[type=range]').each(function(){this.value=newValue});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
<input type="range">
<input type="range">
<span id="value"></span>
</body>
</html>
```